# Trouble with TableRowSorter and illegal comparator casting

Tags: java, swing, sorting, jtable

just wondering why table row sorting with a comparator on a particular column isn't working. The dialog is pictured below, with the 'Item Types' table being sorted.

[image: Image of items/item groups dialog]

The 'name' column works fine, as you can see. If I click on the ID column, I get

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
    at org.overlord.rfm.rfcsv.ItemGroupsDialog$ItemTable$2.compare(ItemGroupsDialog.java:1)
```

Here is where the row sorter is defined and used:

```
        rowSorter = new TableRowSorter<>(model);

        rowSorter.setComparator(1, new Comparator<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
                return (o1<o2 ? -1 : (o1.equals(o2) ? 0 : 1));
            }
        });
        rowSorter.setSortable(1, true);
        rowSorter.setComparator(2, new HumaneStringComparator());
        rowSorter.setSortable(2, true);
        rowSorter.setRowFilter(searchFilter);
        setRowSorter(rowSorter);
```

This is in the table model, which all seems normal:

```
    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        if (columnIndex < 0 || columnIndex >= 3) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Illegal col index: " + columnIndex);
        }
        if (rowIndex < 0 || rowIndex >= rows.size()) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Illegal row index: " + rowIndex);
        }
        ItemRow ir = rows.get(rowIndex);
        switch (columnIndex) {
            case 0: return ir.getItem().getImage(); 
            case 1: return ir.getItem().getId();
            case 2: return ir.getItem().getName();
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException("Column index invalid?");
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        switch (columnIndex) {
            case 0: return Image.class;
            case 1: return Integer.class;
            case 2: return String.class;
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException("Column index invalid?");
    }
```

What is going wrong? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Quick check: `ItemRow.getItem().getId()` returns an `Integer`, not a `String`, right?

Comment: Err, oops. ;) It returns a String. That would be the problem, yes ;) (if you post this as an answer, I'll accept your answer). I forgot that the ID was actually a string because I was adding a letter to the end of it to indicate broken items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A significant source of `ClassCastException` when using a `JTable` is the combination of `getValueAt`, `getColumnClass` and the best-effort (rather than fail-fast) behaviour of the default renderers.

Here, you declare that the type of your second column (column 1) is `Integer`, and you set the `Comparator` used for it to an `Integer` comparator. Seems quite reasonable so far. However, you are actually free to return *anything* in your `getValueAt` method, and unless you specify a custom renderer - your non-Integer values will render just fine. The compiler cannot check that the types you declare actually match! Due to this, you can only find a class mismatch by careful checking, setting custom renderers/editors or trying to sort (as default comparators are not as lenient).

In this case, it turned out that `getId()` actually returns a `String` instead of an `Integer`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a comparator that expects a Integer but is receiving a String.

```
rowSorter.setComparator(1, new Comparator<String>() {
      @Override
      public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
         Integer i1 = Integer.parseInt(s1);
         Integer i2 = Integer.parseInt(s2);
         return i1.compareTo(i2);
     }
 });
```

You may want to write a try-catch block.

Comment: How it a receiving a String? That's precisely my question

Comment: I think that when you click the ID's columns' header the tablerowsorter sends the values to the integer comparator. Surely this values are strings ("299", "60", etc).

Comment: @PacoAbato How about you ask for clarification in comments to the question, rather than *guess stuff in comments to your own answer*?

Comment: I can't test right now. I wrote it without a compiler at hand. I edit generics. But the idea is what matters, I think.